# can't start neo4j after upgrading from 2.1.7 to 2.2.0

Tags: neo4j

When I click "Start" I get the following alert:

`Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@50e0c7' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.`

(There is no attached exception, despite what the message says.)

That's what happens when I try to connect to my existing database.
I'm on Windows Server 2012.

I also tried creating an empty folder and pointing to it instead, but then when I go to localhost:7474 (on Chrome) Neo4j asks for login and password (!!??) and when I supply the default ones (neo4j and neo4j) and click "Connect" nothing happens.

Things worked fine with 2.1.7.

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled Neo4j and the problem persists, just the same.

Comment: I just tried installing as admin, still no joy - same errors.

Comment: Did you enable the option `allow_store_upgrade=true` in your neo4j.properties?

Comment: Just did. Still no joy.

Comment: I realize now that 2.2.0 is a rather [substantial](http://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-2-2-0/) release. I just reverted to 2.1.8 and that worked fine, so I'm staying with 2.1.8 for now.